# How to add Partial view to layout page in mvc core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to display a dynamic menu in layout page in my ecommerce website using mvc core 3.1 i dont know how to add controller to partial view or is there a better way to render the partial view in core

Below is my code

```
<partial name="_MegaMenu"/>
```

My Partial view

```
@model IEnumerable<SmartEcom.Models.Nav>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li class="submenu">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-submenu">@item.Title</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Slider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-2.html">Video Background</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-3.html">Vertical Slider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index-4.html">GDPR Cookie Bar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
</ul>
```

Below is my controller

```
 public IActionResult PartialViewMegaMenu()
        {
            var navigationlist = _unitOfWork.Nav.GetAll();
            return PartialView("_MegaMenu",navigationlist);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a view component, here, not a partial view.

```
public class MegaMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MegaMenuViewComponent(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork; 
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var navigationlist = _unitOfWork.Nav.GetAll();
        return View(navigationlist);
    }
}
```

Then, put the HTML for what was your partial into a view at `~/Views/Shared/Components/MegaMenu/Default.cshtml`. Finally, in your layout add the following where you want the menu to appear:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MegaMenu")
```

See the [documentation on view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

in mvc core You need to use ViewComponent instead partial view.

create folder with the name  "Component"  and add class same MegaMenuViewComponent .
The class must inherit from the ViewComponent.

```
public class MegaMenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public MegaMenuViewComponent(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork; 
    }

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
    {
        var navigationlist = _unitOfWork.Nav.GetAll();
        return View("Default.cshtml",navigationlist);
    }
}
```

I had the same problem and the problem was solved by placing the view at

```
~/Views/Shared/Default.cshtml
```

then put this code in Layout :

@await Component.InvokeAsync("MegaMenu")